# sklearn train_test_split broken

Tags: python, scikit-learn

my data has the shape ‍`(345438, 5)`, and all I am doing is reading the data and then splitting it with sklearn `train_test_split`. I have done it a lot of times, this is the first time I have ever seen this issue.

Here is my code:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(data[['review','clean_nltk','clean_spacy','clean_sklearn']],data.recommendation,test_size=0.3, stratify=data.recommendation,random_state=100)
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
```

output:

```
(5572, 4)
(335336, 4)
```

when I change the `test_size` parameter to 0.5, it gives:

output:

```
(11086, 4)
(5727, 4)
```

The issue I'm having is that:

1. The `train_test_split` is not splitting the data in the requested proportion.
2. It isn't even conserving the entire data set when splitting. My friend is using the exact same code and he is able to get the right split for the data, we are using the same `random_state` and everything.

What went wrong here?

Comment: New discovery, when I remove stratify, the proportion becomes proper. So something went wrong with the `stratify` parameter

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. can you test your code for example on iris?